# using OSPF over PE-CE Links in VPNs

Tags: vpn, bgp, ospf, vrf, mpls-vpn

```
      area0                     area0
```

CE1----------PE1-----------PE2-------------CE2

```
     N1                       N2
```

CE1,CE2 are same customer edge routers. PE1,PE2 are provider Edge routers of same ISP. and they connected as show in image.

we are running OSPF between PE,CE for BGP/MPLS IP VPNs. PE1-CE1 (Network N1) & PE2-CE2 (Network N2) links are in area0.

OSPF on PE1,PE2 have same domain ID configured to make OSPF routes from one CE to other treated as IA routes.

Question:

Now the N1 is connected network to PE1 and Administrative distance for connected is higher than OSPF. so,PE1 will have N1 as connected route.

Then we have only choice to redistribute the N1 to CE2 is by enabling 'redistribute connected' in BGP of PE1. As the domain ID will not be inserted when redistributing connected routes, CE2 will treat it as External Type 2 Network.

Doesn't it wrong to treat a network of same area/domain as external..?

Comment: just curious, ...I have heard of [such CPE configurations](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_0s/feature/guide/seipecec.html) but always thought they were overly complicated.  Do you own the CPE (CE routers)?  Was the provider unable to deliver a layer 2 WAN, or a [VPLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Private_LAN_Service)?

Comment: I'm a network test engineer. I'm just testing some scenarios in our lab.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have enabled OSPF on the connected interface, it will be an internal route for the networks behind the CE1.

But all OSPF routes on the CE1 side will be external routes on the CE2 side, because they all are redistributed to/from mBGP.  To make them internal, you need a sham link.

Administrative distance doesn't really come into play here.  AD affects how the router forwards packets, but not necessarily what the routing protocol does.

Comment: Thanks Ron,I forgot to mention this point.

Same domain ID configured in OSPF of PE1,PE2.
now BGP will distribute them with LSA3.

Comment: does it correct to treat CE-PE links as _external_..? even after setting same domain ID!

Comment: If they're the same domain ID, they're internal routes,

Comment: But this is what happening in my case: 

the BGP configured in PE1 is taking N1 as connected. so, it not advertising N1 towards CE2 since we said only _redistribute ospf_. 

if we do _redistribute connected_, it advertising N1 as external. 

**doesn't it volation accroding to OSPF..?** same area routes are showing as E2

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your diagram.  Is N1  the link between CE1 and PE1 running OSPF?  If so, it should be an internal route because you have ospf on that interface.

Comment: yes N1 is link between PE1& CE1. 
I want to clear one thing here, any OSPF network other than N1 which is on CE1 side getting redistributed as IA towards CE2. 

only N1 is going as external & we found following reason in debug.

N1 is a connected network to PE1 & As connected having more priority than OSPF , PE1 redistributing it without domain ID inserted which making it appear as External at CE2 .  

Could you please provide me strong argument or any link reasons N1 to be IA at CE2..? What happening in our case is valid or not..? I tired studding couple of RFCs but couldn't help.